# AttributeError: Generic detail view must be called with either an object pk or a slug

Tags: python, django

Cant get access to data in my model, getting next error: AttributeError: Generic detail view Myview must be called with either an object pk or a slug.

My model:

```
class product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 5000)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

my views:

```
class Myview(DetailView):
    queryset = product.objects.all()
    template_name = 'templates/products.html'
```

my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^products/', Myview.as_view(), name='products'),
   ]
```

If there is any another legit way to get data from my model i can change my views and urls correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Generic `DetailView` is for fetching info about a single instance of your model.

Since you are fetching all `product`s (in line `product.objects.all()`) it looks like you want to display a list of products. In this case you must use [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview).

```
class MyView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'templates/products.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the URL you must deliver the pk as a parameter to obtain the element

`url(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', Myview.as_view(), name='products'),`